Export OSM data including bicycle routes releations (Osmium export GeoJSON filters those)
I've used osmium export before to export ways to geojson.
Now my input data (osm.pbf) also includes relations, which I also want to export.
Unfortunately, the Osmium export GeoJSON only contains relations with route=ferry etc. but none with route=bicycle. I double checked, that the original osm.pbf file contains those bicycle routes.
How to export the relations?

I ended up "exporting" the bicycle relations in the original OSM XML format and am going to load the data (and geometry) the relation references "manually".
I'm using --omit-referenced as I only want to load the relations for now (I already have the ways in another data set).
osmium tags-filter germany-latest.osm.pbf -o relations_route-bicycle.osm.xml \
  r/route=bicycle --overwrite --omit-referenced

osmium tags-filter relations_route-bicycle.osm.xml \
  -o relations_route-bicycle_type-route.osm.xml \
  r/type=route --overwrite --omit-referenced

Why the route=bicycle relations are not in the Osmium GeoJSON export
I think the issue is that the route=bicycle relation consists of ways (or even other relations), so osmium would have to look up the nodes of the ways which might be too much work?
  <relation id="13068" version="300" timestamp="2024-07-28T18:45:56Z">
    <member type="way" ref="24543938" role=""/>
    ...
    <member type="way" ref="34238509" role=""/>
    ...
    <tag k="network" v="rcn"/>
    <tag k="route" v="bicycle"/>
    <tag k="type" v="route"/>
    ...
  </relation>

The route=ferry seems to be tagged directly to the ways which consists of nodes, so only the node geometry has to be looked up:
  <way id="8255835" version="19" timestamp="2021-03-02T17:17:12Z">
    <nd ref="86106056"/>
    <nd ref="300319974"/>
    <tag k="bicycle" v="yes"/>
    ...
    <tag k="route" v="ferry"/>
  </way>

GeoJson of a ferry route:
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[13.883699,50.9806137],[13.8851345,50.9801962]]},"properties":{"bicycle":"yes","foot":"yes","motor_vehicle":"no","motorcar":"no","motorcycle":"yes","name":"Fährstelle Birkwitz-Heidenau","opening_hours":"Mo-Fr 04:30-23:00; Sa,Su 07:00-23:00","ref":"F10","route":"ferry"}},

So my guess is, that osmium only extracts ways, not "really" relations, as they don't have their own geometry.
